# Why does a reduction from a P-problem to an NP-complete problem not show that P=NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, np, p-vs-np

Consider the following problem, called BoxDepth:

> Given a set of $n$ axis-aligned rectangles in the plane, how big is the largest subset of these rectangles that contain a common point?

Say we proved these two statements:

1. There is a a polynomial-time reduction from BoxDepth to MaxClique.
2. There is a polynomial-time algorithm for BoxDepth with $O(n^3)$ runtime.

Why don’t these two results imply that P=NP?

Comment: Well, suppose there are $k'$ intersecting rectangles: what structure does that imply in the graph? Suppose there's a $k$-clique in the graph: what structure does that imply in the rectangles?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question; you can not "prove a reduction". Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Since you already got an answer for c, I'm going to remove the others; feel free to repost them (one at a time).

Comment: You'll note that the new, better title pretty much answers the question.

Answer (score 7):

Part 1 shows how to solve BoxDepth using MaxClique.

Part 2 shows how to solve BoxDepth directly.

None of the parts says anything about solving MaxClique.